# 2014 Chevy Traverse Smells Hot

Tags: chevrolet, troubleshooting, smell, traverse

My 2014 Chevy Traverse AWD started getting a hot/burning smell. There are no detectable leaks, verified by our mechanic.  Oil has been changed, transmission had a drain/fill. Coolant levels are good. Brake fluid levels are good as well. Operating temperature is right at 210F, right where it should be.

The only time I get this smell is after the vehicle has been running for a while, driving to work (roughly 40 miles). Driving around in town and it doesn't seem to happen.

What can I check or look at to help diagnose or get me pointed in the right direction? To me, it doesn't smell like burning oil.

Answer (score 1):

Carefully feel the metal parts of the wheels after driving to work. Use caution, one of them may be blazing hot. If so, you may have a brake problem.

Comment: Front brake pads, calipers and rotors were replaced about a year ago but I will check that out this morning.

Comment: @matt. Another failure mode for brakes is internal collapse within the brake hose. The hose would act like a 1-way valve, causing the caliper to continue squeezing after the brake pedal is released. Test 1: Jack it up, spin the wheel, step on pedal, release. If the wheel now won't spin it could be a bad hose. Test 2: Step on pedal, release. Open bleeder slightly. If fluid shoots out under pressure, probably a bad hose.